# Description and Xpath in FHIR Custom Search Parameter

Tags: hl7-fhir

I have registered this extension under an Imaging Study Resource and added a Custom Search Parameter for it.

```
"extension": [{
  "url": "http://example.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/middlename-extension",
  "extension": [{
    "url": "middlename",
    "valueString": "Rocky"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I want to now search for the valueString "Rocky" across the server and return any Imaging Study which has this extension value.

How can I define the Description and Xpath while registering the search parameter for this usecase?

I tried this but this would not work, am i missing something?

```
"expression" : "ImagingStudy.extension.where(url='http://example.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/middlename-extension').extension(url='middlename').value.as(String)",
"xpath" : "f:ImagingStudy/f:extension/f:extension/f:value/f:as[@valueString]"
```

Comment: What server are you using? And did you look at this example: http://hl7.org/fhir/searchparameter-example-extension.json.html?

Comment: I am using Hapi-Fhir.

Answer (score 0):

The expression should either be
`"ImagingStudy.extension.where(url='http://example.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/middlename-extension').extension.where(url='middlename').value.as(String)"`
or
`"ImagingStudy.extension('http://example.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/middlename-extension').extension('middlename').value.as(String)"`

The xPath isn't used by any servers that I'm aware of, but for the record, it should be:
`"f:ImagingStudy/f:extension[@url='http://example.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/middlename-extension']/f:extension[@url='middlename']/f:valueString/@value"`

As a side note, you shouldn't be using a custom extension for the middle name.  Middle names are conveyed as any repetition of HumanName.given other than the first.  If you want to send a middle name without a first name, you could put a dataAbsentReason extension on the first 'given' repetition.

Comment: Hi Lloyd, I will keep that in mind. Also the first expression you gave worked.